# Cant get value back from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, post

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'post.php',           
    data: dataString,
    success:function (data) {
        if (data==null) { alert("darnit!!!!");}    
            //$("#response").append(data);
            alert(dataString);
        }          
    });     
});
```

in PHP file just a simple

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Also tried

```
echo "got iT!";
```

But nothing, been looking of over tried differant things but no luck
first  `//alert (dataString);` works
but after the `success:function (data)` I don't get any alerts - no response within the page!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about firebug? Are you sure the ajax request is sent?

Comment: @Grmn: Just so you know, there is a "Code Sample" button in the text editor that will automatically indent your code 4 spaces.

Comment: You've got mismatching brackets, maybe fixing these will help?

Comment: You have a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry Colin, Tim could you explain, cause i am really not seeing it!

Comment: Try defining an `error: function(jqXHR) { alert(jqXHR.status); }` handler and I'll place a lot of money on it alerting either `404` or `500`

Comment: $("#send").click(function () { is the very start... of that post form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a SyntaxError in your snippet. I'm not sure if that's also in your real code.

Be sure to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) in your PHP file and `dataType: 'json'` in [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). And always use an `error` callback as well. You don't want your application to become indefinitely frozen if something fails.

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php',        
    data: {
        action: 'greet',
        foo: 'bar',
        baz: 'quux'
    }, 
    type: 'POST',  
    dataType: 'json',
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); // DEBUG
    if (response.error) {
        alert('Greet Error: ' + response.error);
    } else {
        alert(response.greet);
    }
}).catch(function (jqXHR) {
    console.log('AJAX Error', jqXHR); // DEBUG
    alert('AJAX Error: Request failed');
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$input = $_POST;
$response = array();

if (!isset($input['action'])) {
    $response['error'] = 'Action parameter required';
} else {
    if ($input['action'] === 'greet') {
        if (!isset($input['foo']) || !isset($input['bar'])) {
            $response['error'] = 'Invalid greet request';
        } else {
            $response['greet'] = 'Welcome home, David!';
        }
    } else {
        $response['error'] = 'Unknown action';
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: @Grmn: Well, with all due respect, that's your problem. Check out your debugger and find out why the request failed. The error is likely caused by your server or your code. Do you have PHP installed?  Is file path correct?

Comment: I am localhost at the moment, Ubuntu (php5, mysqli)

Comment: I made a few adjustments, try again :)

Comment: i would of liked saying that worked, but same response type.. Ajax error doenst even call the php page

Comment: Check the output in the console of your browser. There should be information there that helps you. If you don't know what the console is (I recommend using Chrome during web development), this link may help you: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console . If you use Firefox, you may want to look into FireBug (google it).

Comment: I have firebug install in FF, to see if it was maybe my FF ran page in Chromium. (no errors shown in FF Firebug.) What could be the reason that Ajax has problems.

Comment: I'm not gonna say it again: Debug it! Log the error callback arguments, and read. The information is right there. If the HTTP request does start, you can trace that as well.

Comment: i'd hope that this makes more sence to you then it does to me, only error given is in jquery script itself v1.7.1 error given xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Answer (score 0):

JQuery ignoring your data return usually means it doesn't understand the format that's being returned, or doesn't know what to expect. Set the dataType to an acceptable format and also double check that your PHP script is actually sending something back to the page in Firebug's console.

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'post.php',           
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'text',
    success:function (data) {
        if (data==null) { alert("darnit!!!!");}    
            //$("#response").append(data);
            alert(dataString);
        }          
    });     
});
```

Comment: `Enclose 'dataString' in inverted commas` why ?

Comment: @pomeh Sorry, my mistake - automatically assumed dataString was an acceptable data type. Shouldn't be posting while on the phone... I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First: you missed dataType property from ajax function, next, you need to pass json type data, and you had a syntax error in code, try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'post.php',
    dataType: 'text',           
    data: {
        data_to_pass: dataString
    },
    success:function (data) {
        if (data==null) { 
            alert("darnit!!!!");
        } else {    
            //$("#response").append(data);
            alert(dataString);
        }          
    });     
});
```

in PHP:

```
$dataString = $_POST['data_to_pass'];
if($dataString) {
    echo "got IT!";
}
```

Comment: sorry tried both of the above ditn work, also, how do i get the "like" tinymce editor on my screen, dont see it

Comment: What does browser debug control (F12) say? Maybe bad linking to php file?

Comment: throw Components.Exception("prompt aborted by user", Cr.NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) nsPrompter.js (line 457)

Comment: badlinking that would of been stupid but nice! but no! i did it using full url eg: http://localhost/path/page.php

Answer (score 0):

I would like share the following, and I think I've solved the problem.

Besides the fact that I did made a mistake, retrieving the values from the form a bit wrong.
so the first alert gave me `name=[Object name]`, now that was stupid.

The problem of not getting results seemed to be a problem with jquery itself, in my case.
I do not know if it is the same problem other people are having. I replaced the included file of jquery 1.7 with 1.4.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

than with the following code (only from $.ajax).

```
var dataString = $("#contactForm").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './php/mail.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg){
        if (msg === 'sent'){
            $('#success').text('Message sent!');
        } else{
            $('#success').text('Mail Error. Please Try Again.!');   
        }
    }
});
```

Now i have it working - and gonna tweak it a bit to my needs!

Thx all for all help!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'post.php',           
    data: dataString,
    success:function (data) {
        if (data===undefined) { alert("darnit!!!!");}    
            //$("#response").append(data);
            alert(data);
        }          
    });     
});
```

Also I would look into using json_encode on an array in your php file and returning a json object.

Comment: Ill have a look at json, but should it not atleast alert data within the success function, i dont get any response within the success function

Comment: I was just pointing out that you were using == instead of === in your if statement which is a bad habit and that you would be trying to alert data and not dataString since you were within the success callback. If you use the firebug extension with the Firefox browser that should help you debug your ajax post. Most likely there is an error causing it to not post.